# What would cause this noise/distortion and how to fix it?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

What type of distortion is this? What is causing it, and how can I fix it?

This seems to happen only with very low-value resistors on the output (less than 50 Ω), and gets worse the lower the resistor value is. Without any load, the signal is very clean.

I am using an [LM675](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm675) op-amp.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The input (Vdrive) is a 700 Hz, 24 V sinusoid. I am measuring the output right at pin 4 of the op-amp.

Comment: Power supply decoupling capacitor --> have you used them? Are they mounted on your circuit board close to the op-amp where they are needed? What type of capacitors have you used?

Comment: Yes. the power supply noise is the 300 KHz you see on the white line - that I am not too concerned with. I am more concerned with the large spikes on the blue line.

Comment: Where does your 0-24V signal fall between the +48 and -Batt voltages?

Comment: I have 2 supplies. a 24V battery and a 24 to 48 converter.

Comment: Measure Vcc and Vee.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Power opamps are usually not unity gain stable because the intended use is to amplify a low level signal to a much higher voltage. Making the chip unity gain stable would waste some valuable gain-bandwidth by using too much internal compensation, whereas setting a minimum gain of 10 allows less compensation, thus an extra 20dB of feedback to correct output stage distortion, which usually is sorely needed.

So your closed loop gain is simply too low. You can increase it, or shape the feedback so you only have x10 gain at "high" frequency and keep low gain at low frequency.

Note R9/C9 definitely count, I'm not sure what they're supposed to do but they look like they belong to the sort of active filter that requires an unity gain stable opamp.

> This seems to happen only with very low-value resistors on the output (less than 50 Ω)

The problem is too much gain ; bipolar transconductance is proportional to current, so high current increases open loop gain a bit. Only up to a point, because too much current will make the transistors lose gain but they also lose of fT which makes it worse.

After reading ErnestoG's answer I realized this amp doesn't have rail to rail inputs, so reducing the gain with a single supply is going to require some creativity. Inputs can't go below 3V from the negative rail, which is not very convenient if your input is a low voltage signal referenced to the negative rail. You'll probably need to shift/boost voltage with another opamp. Could wrap this opamp's feedback around the LM675 to not have to think about offset voltage...

Another solution: if this is a dominant pole compensated opamp (I didn't check) the stability condition of having gain>10 only applies at frequencies close enough to the unity gain frequency of the opamp. So it is possible to cheat by making a circuit that has the required gain>10 at high frequency, but the gain you want at low frequency. If the goal is to drive something slow like a motor or a coil, it's not a problem.

[image]

Comment: This. That is what I am trying to figure out. I can try to lower my input and increase my gain.

Comment: I see. Is there any simpler way? I am just having a hard time understanding where this random 150 kHz noise is coming from? Is it switching noise somewhere within the op amp?

Comment: When it gets unstable it will oscillate, amplify its own noise, and do other crazy things ; since phase margin depends on output current/voltage, if it is on the edge between stable and unstable some values of output current/voltage may be stable and other not, so it will throw bursts of oscillations when it feels like it, and otherwise work fine on the rest of the signal, exactly as you're seeing.

Comment: If it's guaranteed stable for a gain of 10, the only solution is to use a gain of 10... but you can cheat, see edit

Answer (score 0):

We do not know why you did not look at the LM675 datasheet:
[image: LM675]

Comment: I have this network built into the circuit and did not change or contribute anything when testing

Comment: Maybe you built the circuit with a mess of long wires on a breadboard? Each wire has inductance and the rows of contacts and wires all over the place have capacitance between them.